# C++/Raspberry Pi/Mosquitto API: Attempting to publish a string message to MQTT broker with Mosquitto, but keep getting inaccessible memory errors

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, segmentation-fault, mqtt, mosquitto

As the title says I'm using [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html) to publish a string. This string is a png that's been encoded into base64. I have a microcontroller on another end waiting to receive this string and then decode back into a png. The microcontroller running this code is a Raspbian RPi 3 B+. The relevant code is here:

```
  printf("Converting out.png to base64 for transmission over MQTT.\n");
  string encoded_png = base64encoder(); // encode out.png into encoded_png
  printf("Converted! Size of base64 string encoded from out.png is: %d\n", encoded_png.size());

  const char *ptr = encoded_png.c_str(); // ptr to a null terminated c_str version of encoded_png is generated here
  printf("Ptr's size (should be same as above as ptr refers to the encoded string): %d\n", strlen(ptr));

  printf("Publishing to Pixy_Snapper topic...\n");
  // I keep getting segmentation faults here. The size of ptr is the same as the 
  // size of encoded_png, so I don't see why I keep running into them. 
  mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "Pixy_Snapper", encoded_png.size(), ptr, 0, false);
```

[**mosquitto_publish**](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#mosquitto_publish) needs a few things as argument that I must generate: a valid mosq instance (I've got it), topic to publish to, length of the payload to be sent, and a pointer to payload's location. I've given it the topic, the payload length, and the pointer to payload as specified. In my debugger, I can see that prior to the running of mosquitto_publish that both encoded_png and ptr are properly initialized:

[image: encoded_png is a base64 string and ptr is a pointer to that very string]
**encoded_png** is a base64 string and **ptr** is a pointer to that very string. ptr's mem location is 0x76856008.

[image: debug terminal demonstrates that the size values for both encoded_png and ptr are the same]
debug terminal demonstrates that the size values for both **encoded_png** and **ptr** are the same (size value is 262932)

[image: once I click step over, mosquitto_publish naturally moves to the location the pointer is pointing it to, encoded_png]
once I click step over, **mosquitto_publish** naturally moves to the location the pointer is pointing it to, **encoded_png**

[image: stepping over a final time, the memory location containing encoded_png is somehow unreadable]
stepping over a final time, the memory location containing **encoded_png** is inaccessible.

I don't know why the memory location is inaccessible. The fact that the debugger can show me that the pointer to the memory location of encoded_png actually *contains* encoded_png indicates to me that it *should* be accessible to mosquitto_pub, but for some reason it can't access it. I'm at a loss on what to do to solve this. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you publish anything? Try calling `mosquito_publish(mosq, NULL, "Pixy_Snapper", 11, "Hello World", 0, false);` - does that succeed or crash?

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages, they are really hard to read and impossible for those uses that have to use screen readers. Post the text and use the toolbar to format it.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the length value is right?

Comment: How did you determine that it cannot access it? I dug through mosquitto_publish briefly and it does its best to immediately send the packet or take a copy of the buffer. Your last screenshot is typical for a stack-allocated value that goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: I can't read these images. Repost as text, not images (unless the image is relevant, such as a test png)

Comment: @romkey I stupidly didn't think to try that, but yes it does work. This does indicate to me that the error is related to the length of the payload being inaccurate like hardillb says. I'll try something simple like encoded_png.size() - 1 and see what happens. I edited the original post so that it contains text annotations of the images for those who cannot see their content.

Comment: Alright, simple manipulations of encoded_png.size() like +/-1 aren't working, so I'm going to count the length of the string the old fashioned way with a loop and a counter.

Comment: Yeah, as anticipated, adding a while loop with code `while(encoded_png[i]) i++;` produces the same output as encoded_png.size() and strlen(ptr), aka 262932. So by all appearances it seems I am passing the right length to mosquitto_publish. My debugger won't let me step into mosquitto_publish so I can't explicitly see where things are going wrong.

Comment: Interestingly, if I do the following:  `string test = "Hello World";
int size = test.size();  
const char *testptr = test.c_str();  
mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "topic", size, testptr, 0, false);`  the publish is successful. So something is truly wrong with the encoded_png string size. It must be wildly inaccurate to what the true length of the string is and null characters are getting ran into way earlier than anticipated, despite the fact that I'm getting the same size number no matter how I calculate it.

Comment: Well, the problem is definitely in my base64encode() function. I'll figure it out eventually.